# How to identify if a FCM message is targeted to the FCM client handler or UrbanAirship handler

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, urbanairship.com

I'm using UrbanAirship for my mobile engagement tool in parallel to FCM on Android. Based on the UrbanAirship [documentation](https://docs.urbanairship.com/platform/android/#fcm-setup), in case using my own `FirebaseMessagingService` I need to pass the remote message using `AirshipFirebaseMessagingService.processMessageSync(this, remoteMessage);`

How can I know that the message was not handled by UrbanAirship and I fallback to my own FCM notification builder? There is no return value for the `processMessageSync` method. I noticed that because UrbanAirship handles the message in a synchronous way, they are consuming and nullifying the `notification` field of the `remoteMessage` object. Seems strange to me that they haven't exposed any property or return value.

This is the code that worked for me (part of my `AppFirebaseMessageService.java`)

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    AirshipFirebaseMessagingService.processMessageSync(this, remoteMessage);

    if (remoteMessage != null && remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        handleInternalFcm(remoteMessage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got response from UrbanAirship's support. That's the official way knowning if a message can be handled by UA:

```
PushMessage pushMessage = new PushMessage(message.getData());
if (pushMessage.containsAirshipKeys()) {
    //will be handled by UrbanAirship
}
```